# VS 2019 Running MSTest in MTA

Tags: c#, mstest, sta, mta

We have a legacy application with `ThreadPool` and `WaitHandle`. We wanted to write Unit-Tests using **MSTest** against it. We ran into a problem where by default MSTest runs in STA (Single Thread Apartment) mode and the test was throwing the following exception,

> System.NotSupportedException: WaitAll for multiple handles on a STA
>   thread is not supported.    at
>   System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitMultiple(WaitHandle[] waitHandles,
>   Int32 millisecondsTimeout, Boolean exitContext, Boolean WaitAll)    at
>   System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitAll(WaitHandle[] waitHandles, Int32
>   millisecondsTimeout, Boolean exitContext)    at
>   System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitAll(WaitHandle[] waitHandles, TimeSpan
>   timeout, Boolean exitContext)

Answer (score 2):

After researching for a while, we found how to change the test settings from STA to MTA.

1. Add a `test.runsettings` file to you solution's folder

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RunSettings>
     <RunConfiguration>
         <ExecutionThreadApartmentState>MTA</ExecutionThreadApartmentState>
     </RunConfiguration>
   </RunSettings>
   ```
2. Edit `**.Test.csproj` file and refer the `test.runsettings` file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
      ...  
      <RunSettingsFilePath>$(SolutionDir)\test.runsettings</RunSettingsFilePath>
      ...
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Now run your test, it should work.